# Get element tapped/clicked (this) with hammer.js

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

is there a way to retrieve the element clicked or tapped with hammer.js:

I have tried the normal way like so:

```
$("#shopbystyleContent li a").hammer().on("tap",  function(event) {

var imgLarge = $(this).parent().find('img.imgLarge').attr("src");
.....
```

But $(this) returns [object Object].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

event.target should return the tapped element according to hammer.js's [Getting Started](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started#event-data) page.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is correct, however note that the hammer.js events do not currently have the "currentTarget" (that is, the element on which the handler was bound).  This is being tracked in https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/807.